# Wordpress on XAMPP over my home network

Tags: xampp, windows

I've installed WordPress on XAMPP on a Windows 7 machine (192.168.3.3) on my home network. I can see the XAMPP Welcome page from my other Win7 machine (192.168.3.2) but cannot access Wordpress from it? Is anyone able to offer any advice?

Comment: This seems like an XAMPP issue, not a WordPress issue.

Comment: Hosting issues are hosting issues, not WordPress issues. You wouldn't contact a florists if you had a broken window because you just happened to have lots of flowers in the house

Comment: Apologies 1st of all I'll read the help centre. Thanks for the help that is here

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what "cannot access WordPress from [other Win7 machine on network]" actually means.

I have this same setup and it works fine.

Be sure to check these things:

1. Do you have Apache and MySQL services running? Check XAMPP Control Panel
2. Can your other Win7 machine access the folder WP is in? ie. 192.168.3.3/dir-wp-is-in/
3. Can your server machine see the WordPress site? ie. localhost/dir-wp-is-in/ or 192.168.3.3/dir-wp-is-in/
4. Is your WordPress settings set properly? My settings are usually...  Settings->General->WP Address = http://192.168.3.3/dir-wp-is-in  ... and the same for Site Address

I'd have made this a comment, but I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to 192.168.3.3:80/your_wp. Your Apache is listening on this port, he will know what to do.